# Ordering by date not working

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I need to filter the information in my database by date, but it doesn't work. The format of the date in my database is as so

> Thu Nov 10 00:00:00 GMT+00:00 2016

The database query is:

```
public Cursor ObterTodasAsReceitasPorUsuario (String cod_usuario){
        db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        String tp_lancamento = "r";
        String sql = String.format("SELECT * FROM %s WHERE %s=? AND %s=? ORDER BY DATE(%s) DESC",
                Tabelas.LANCAMENTO, Lancamento.COD_USUARIO, Lancamento.TP_LANCAMENTO, Lancamento.DATA);
        String[] selectionArgs = {cod_usuario, tp_lancamento};
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(sql, selectionArgs);
        Log.d("Despesas", "Despesas");
        DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor(cursor);
        db.close();
        return cursor;
    }
```

This is the [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LyWnR.jpg) after ordering. Any suggestions on how to solve this?

Comment: How does it not work?  Do you get an error?  If so what?  Is the ordering unexpected?  If so, how?

Comment: Thanks for responding, It works without showing any error, the problem is doesn't sort  the records by date, I upload an image to show.

Comment: Is it necessary to have the date in the formst you mentioned above? Couldn't you just do `dd/mm/yyyy` and then sort the dates? It would make the sorting a bit easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend that you format your date like so:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/YYYY");
String date = format.format(calendar.getTime());
```

After you have formated the date, insert it into your database. Then, use the following query to sort the dates:

```
SELECT * FROM Table ORDER BY date(dateColumn)
```

For more ways of formating the date, see [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) post.